# Jquery css method does not set CSS3 variables

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good day,

I am working with CSS3 variables to offset items and many other things in runtime however JQuery's css method ignores any attempt at setting a css var. I try the following

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#testdiv').css('--bgc','rgb(0,0,255)');
    });
```

```css
 div
    {
        --bgc:rgb(255,0,0);
        background-color:var(--bgc);
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

So in theory the div should initially load as a 50px by 50px red box and as soon as page loading is complete change into a blue box however the --bgc variable is never changed on the DIV. Is there any way to set this in JQuery?

Comment: @AnujKumar read the title

Comment: @AnujKumar that is a css variable, see the css class added in the post.

Comment: @UgoT. Read the title and use Goog

Comment: I ask because I never heard of it. Try background-color instead.

Comment: try as attribute  $('#testdiv').attr("style","--bgc:rgb(0,0,255)");

Comment: What some of you are suggesting defeats the purpose of using the variable. He wants to to change the variable, not the element style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a pure JavaScript solution:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bgc', 'rgb(0,0,255)');
});
```

CSS:

```
:root {
    --bgc: rgb(255,0,0);
}

div {
    background-color:var(--bgc);
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/theblindprophet/pen/yJpZNb

Reference: [Variables why should you care?](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/css-variables-why-should-you-care?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, I wanted to be able to set it on JQuery collections but I gues $().each() will have to do

Answer (score 0):

You can set variable via vanilla javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testdiv')[0].style.setProperty('--bgc', 'rgb(0, 0,255)');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testdiv')[0].style.setProperty('--bgc', 'rgb(0,0,255)');
});
```

```css
div
{
    --bgc:rgb(255,0,0);
    background-color:var(--bgc);
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

Comment: where is vanilla javascript in your answer?

Comment: `$('#testdiv')` doesn't return an array. You shouldn't need the `[0]`

Comment: @Jai here: `.style.setProperty()`
@theblindprophet try it without the `[0]`

Comment: @user1636505 yet that is not vanilla javascript. You are still in jquery and you are converting a jq object to the dom node.

Comment: @Jai I've used jQuery so that OP can see the diff

Comment: @theblindprophet $('#testdiv') returns a JQuery collection holding only 1 item. As style.setProperty is vanilla and not present in a JQuery collection JS he has to access the first DOM element in the collection with the [0].